# how to make a pie graph only name top n performance

Tags: r, pie-chart

I haven't been using pie graph a lot in r, is there a way to make a pie graph and only show the top 10 names with percentage?

For example, here's a simple version of my data:

```
> data
   count    METRIC_ID
1      8           71
2      2         1035
3      5         1219
4      4         1277
5      1         1322
6      3         1444
7      5         1462
8     17         1720
9      6         2019
10     2         2040
11     1         2413
12    11         2489
13    24         2610
14    29         2737
15     1         2907
16     1         2930
17     2         2992
18     1         2994
19     2         3020
20     4         3045
21    35         3222
22     2         3245
23     5         3306
24     2         3348
25     2         3355
26     2         3381
27     3         3383
28     4         3389
29     6         3404
30     1         3443
31    22         3465
32     3         3558
33    15         3600
34     3         3730
35     6         3750
36     1         3863
37     1         3908
38     5         3913
39     3         3968
40     9         3972
41     2         3978
42     5         4077
43     4         4086
44     3         4124
45     2         4165
46     3         4205
47     8         4206
48     4         4210
49    12         4222
50     4         4228
```

and I want to see the count of each METRIC_ID's distribution:

```
pie(data$count, data$METRIC_ID)
```

But this Chart marks every single METRIC_ID on the graph, when I have over 100 METRIC_ID, it looks like a mess. How can I only mark the top n (for example, n=5) METRIC_ID on the graph, and show the count of that n METRIC_ID only?

Thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To suppress plotting of some labels, set them to `NA`. Try this:

```
labls <- data$METRIC_ID
labls[data$count <  3] <- NA
pie(data$count, paste(labls))
```

Comment: I tried to set them to "", and it solves my problem perfectly! Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Simply subset your data before creating the piechart. I'd do somehting like:

1. Sort your datasets using `order`.
2. Select the first ten rows.
3. Create the pie chart from the resulting data.

Pie charts are not the best way to visualize your data, just google `pie chart problems`, e.g. [this link](http://www.juiceanalytics.com/writing/the-problem-with-pie-charts/). I'd go for something like:

```
library(ggplot2)
dat = dat[order(-dat$count),]
dat = within(dat, {METRIC_ID = factor(METRIC_ID, levels = METRIC_ID)})
ggplot(dat, aes(x = METRIC_ID, y = count)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

Here I just plot all the data, which I think still leads to a readable graph. This graph is more formally known as a dotplot, and is heavily used in the [graphics book of Cleveland](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0963488414). Here the height is linked to `count`, which is much easier to interpret that linking `count` to the fraction of the area of a circle, as in the case of the piechart.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply @Paul Hiemstra ! I thought about that, but my goal was to show my customer that the problem is kinda evenly distributed amount all METRIC_IDs...so I was looking for a graph to show them all METRIC_ID was mostly evenly sliced --- I thought of pie graph. It's important for me to show them ALL METRIC_IDs distribution, and I need pick out the METRIC_IDs that show the most count of problems and make it visualized to customer...for my analyzing purpose I don't need this...but I need a pretty graph to show...any idea that I could satisfy all these conditions? Thanks!!

Comment: Improved the plot a bit, ordered by `count`, swapped x and y axis.

Comment: Questions like: "which metric id is largest", "how much larger is this id than that id" are much easier to answer using this dotplot.

Comment: Got it! I've never tried ggplot2 package mainly I don't graph that much..will dig more into it. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Find a better type of chart for your data.

Here is a possibility to create the chart you want:

```
data2 <- data[data$count %in% tail(sort(data$count),5),]
pie(data2$count, data2$METRIC_ID)
```

[image]

Slightly better:

```
data3 <- data2
data3$METRIC_ID <- as.character(data3$METRIC_ID)
data3 <- rbind(data3,data.frame(count=sum(data[! data$count %in% tail(sort(data$count),5),"count"]),METRIC_ID="others"))
pie(data3$count, data3$METRIC_ID)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Roland! I think it looks nice to put the others together in one part!