# Plot top n values, group remainders as “others”

Tags: r

I would like to plot a dataframe of 20,000 records each of which is from a country e.g.:

```
df$Country:

Australia  
Australia  
Australia  
Uganda  
Peru  
Peru
```

However if I plot them all it is unreadable, see: http://rpubs.com/onco_p53/country
I would like to just plot the top 10 most frequent countries, and group the rest into an “other countries” category. Ideally using `ggplot2` `geom_bar`

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: You can check `?count` from `dplyr` or `?table` to get the frequency and then use `?top_n` from dplyr.

Comment: I have tried to get solution such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16238147/how-to-make-a-pie-graph-only-name-top-n-performance to work, bu they have a separate "count" column, not counting factors.

Comment: You could perhaps rank the countries by frequency into "top 10" and "other" categories (added extra variable say `classification`) and plot using `facet_wrap(~classification)` on that variable. Use `scales = "free_y"` to adjust limits on y axis, but do issue a warning that these two facets are not comparable. Another way would be to plot both levels of `classification` as separate plots and combine them using `gridExtra::grid.arrange`.

Comment: You could also aggregate your data first (by using `table`, `aggregate`,`dplyr`, etc). Makes finding the top 10 easier too. Then you can use a classifier as @RomanLuštrik mentioned.